# In pytorch, self-made dataset and testing dataset seem to exhaust all RAM

Tags: python, pytorch, ram, mnist

In pytorch, self-made dataset and testing dataset seem to exhaust all RAM

I am new to pytorch and I wrote a ResNet program in pytorch on MNIST for an experiment.

If I use the data loader as below, it is fine:

```python
import torch as pt
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, TensorDataset
import torchvision as ptv

mnist_train = ptv.datasets.MNIST(ROOT_DIR,
                                 train=True,
                                 transform=ptv.transforms.ToTensor(),
                                 download=False)
dl = pt.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset=mnist_train,
                              batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                              shuffle=True,
                              drop_last=True)
```

If I use a self-made dataset as below to use a validation set at each iteration, the program will exhaust all my RAM. The testing set is not used in each iteration, but at the end to evaluate the model.

```python
mnist_test = ptv.datasets.MNIST(ROOT_DIR,
                                train=False,
                                transform=ptv.transforms.ToTensor(),
                                download=False)
M_TEST, PIC_H, PIC_W = mnist_test.data.shape

x_test = mnist_test.data.double() / 255.
y_test = mnist_test.targets

a = pt.randperm(M_TEST)  # ATTENTION pt.randperm
x_test = x_test[a]
y_test = y_test[a]
VAL_RATE = 0.1
M_VAL = int(np.ceil(M_TEST * VAL_RATE))
M_TEST -= M_VAL

x_test, x_val = pt.split(x_test, (M_TEST, M_VAL))
y_test, y_val = pt.split(y_test, (M_TEST, M_VAL))

x_test = x_test.view(-1, 1, PIC_H, PIC_W).double()
x_val = x_val.view(-1, 1, PIC_H, PIC_W).double()

dl_test = DataLoader(TensorDataset(x_test, y_test),
                      batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)

def acc(ht, yt):
    return (pt.argmax(ht, 1) == yt.long()).double().mean()

# in iteration:
    for epoch in range(N_EPOCHS):

        for i, (bx, by) in enumerate(dl):
            model.train(True)
            optim.zero_grad()
            bx = bx.view(-1, 1, PIC_H, PIC_W).double()
            ht = model(bx)
            cost = criterion(ht, by)
            cost.backward()
            optim.step()
            model.train(False)
            accv = acc(ht, by)
            ht_val = model(x_val)
            val_cost = criterion(ht_val, y_val)
            val_acc = acc(ht_val, y_val)
```

So I suspect only the ptv.datasets.MNIST and the pt.utils.data.DataLoader is available, so I removed the usage of my self-made validation set at each iteration; and the RAM usage is normal after the removal. But the test progress still exhaust all my RAM even I only use the ptv.datasets.MNIST and the pt.utils.data.DataLoader as below:

```python
mnist_test = ptv.datasets.MNIST(ROOT_DIR,
                                train=False,
                                transform=ptv.transforms.ToTensor(),
                                download=False)
dl_test = pt.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset=mnist_test,
                              batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                              shuffle=False,
                              drop_last=True)
test_cost_avg = 0.
test_acc_avg = 0.
GROUP = int(np.ceil(M_TEST / BATCH_SIZE / 10))
for i, (bx, by) in enumerate(dl_test):
    bx = bx.view(-1, 1, PIC_H, PIC_W).double()
    ht = model(bx)
    test_cost_avg += criterion(ht, by)
    test_acc_avg += acc(ht, by)
    if i % GROUP == 0:
        print(f'Testing # {i + 1}')
if i % GROUP != 0:
    print(f'Testing # {i + 1}')
test_cost_avg /= i + 1
test_acc_avg /= i + 1
print(f'Tested: cost = {test_cost_avg}, acc = {test_acc_avg}')
print('Over')
```

Please give me a help. Thanks a lot!

Update:

I suspect there is something wrong with my model, because I have a simple CNN model on self-made dataset from pytorchvision's MNIST does not have this RAM exhaustion problem. So I paste my model in this problem as below FYI:

```python
def my_conv(in_side, in_ch, out_ch, kernel, stride, padding='same'):
    if 'same' == padding:
        ps = kernel - 1
        padding = ps // 2
    else:
        padding = 0
    print(padding)  # tmp
    return pt.nn.Conv2d(in_ch, out_ch, kernel_size=kernel, stride=stride, padding=padding)


class MyResnetBlock(pt.nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, residual, in_side, in_ch, out_ch, kernel=3, stride=1, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.residual = residual
        self.in_side = in_side
        self.in_ch = in_ch
        self.out_ch = out_ch
        self.kernel = kernel
        self.stride = stride

        self.conv1 = my_conv(in_side, in_ch, out_ch, kernel, stride)
        self.bn1 = pt.nn.BatchNorm2d(out_ch)
        self.relu1 = pt.nn.ReLU()

        self.conv2 = my_conv(np.ceil(in_side / stride), out_ch, out_ch, kernel, 1)
        self.bn2 = pt.nn.BatchNorm2d(out_ch)
        self.relu2 = pt.nn.ReLU()

        if residual:
            self.conv_down = my_conv(in_side, in_ch, out_ch, kernel, stride)

    def forward(self, input):
        x = input
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = self.bn1(x)
        x = self.relu1(x)

        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = self.bn2(x)

        if self.residual:
            res = self.conv_down(input)
        else:
            res = input
        x += res

        x = self.relu2(x)
        return x


class MyResnetByPt(pt.nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, blocks_spec_list, in_side, init_in_ch, init_out_ch, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.conv1 = my_conv(in_side, init_in_ch, init_out_ch, 3, 1)
        in_ch = out_ch = init_out_ch

        blocks = []
        for block_id, n_blocks in enumerate(blocks_spec_list):
            for layer_id in range(n_blocks):
                if layer_id == 0:
                    if block_id != 0:
                        out_ch *= 2
                    block = MyResnetBlock(True, in_side, in_ch, out_ch, 3, 2)
                    in_ch = out_ch
                    in_side = int(np.ceil(in_side / 2))
                else:
                    block = MyResnetBlock(False, in_side, in_ch, out_ch, 3, 1)
                blocks.append(block)
        self.blocks = pt.nn.Sequential(*blocks)
        self.final_ch = out_ch
        self.avg_pool = pt.nn.AvgPool2d(kernel_size=(in_side, in_side),
                                        stride=(1, 1),
                                        padding=(0, 0))
        self.fc = pt.nn.Linear(out_ch, N_CLS)

    def forward(self, input):
        x = input

        x = self.conv1(x)

        x = self.blocks(x)

        x = self.avg_pool(x)
        x = x.view(-1, self.final_ch)
        x = self.fc(x)
        return x


model = MyResnetByPt([2, 2, 2, 2], PIC_H, 1, 16)
model = model.double()
```

Comment: Not an answer as such, but you might be able to track down where memory usage is coming from a bit better using https://pythonspeed.com/fil

Comment: "pip install filprofiler" gets "ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement filprofiler (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for filprofiler". So, how to install it?

Comment: Have you tried decreasing the batch size?

Comment: @Josmy batch size is 64, rather small.

Comment: @Itamar I Cannot install filprofiler in Windows but I installed one in Linux, and I am investigating my problem with it now.

Comment: Yeah it doesn't support Windows at the moment.